# List all native posts in template page?

Tags: posts, templates

I've created a page template and I want to do a really simple task: List all (native) posts

I have this code inside the template-file:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_type'        => 'post'
);          
$all_posts_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($all_posts_query->have_posts()) : $all_posts_query->the_post(); 
echo '*' . get_the_title() . '*';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo 'DEAD END';
exit;
```

**I want to get all posts**, but I get some error in the returned object which tells it's incorrect post-type (IF I understand it correctly). It does NOT go into the WHILE-loop either. No title is returned.

This is the output of `$all_posts_query`:

```
object(WP_Query)[2627]
  public 'query' => 
    array (size=2)
      'posts_per_page' => int -1
      'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
  public 'query_vars' => 
    array (size=61)
      'posts_per_page' => int -1
      'post_type' => string 'post' (length=4)
      'error' => string '' (length=0)
      'm' => string '' (length=0)
      'p' => int 0
      'post_parent' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost' => string '' (length=0)
      'subpost_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment' => string '' (length=0)
      'attachment_id' => int 0
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'static' => string '' (length=0)
      'pagename' => string '' (length=0)
      'page_id' => int 0
      'second' => string '' (length=0)
      'minute' => string '' (length=0)
      'hour' => string '' (length=0)
      'day' => int 0
      'monthnum' => int 0
      'year' => int 0
      'w' => int 0
      'category_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag' => string '' (length=0)
      'cat' => string '' (length=0)
      'tag_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'author' => string '' (length=0)
      'author_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'feed' => string '' (length=0)
      'tb' => string '' (length=0)
      'paged' => int 0
      'comments_popup' => string '' (length=0)
      'meta_key' => string '' (length=0)
      'meta_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'preview' => string '' (length=0)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
      'sentence' => string '' (length=0)
      'fields' => string '' (length=0)
      'menu_order' => string '' (length=0)
      'category__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'category__not_in' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 4
          1 => int 1
      'category__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'tag_slug__and' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'post_parent__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'author__not_in' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => boolean false
      'suppress_filters' => boolean false
      'cache_results' => boolean true
      'update_post_term_cache' => boolean true
      'update_post_meta_cache' => boolean true
      'nopaging' => boolean true
      'comments_per_page' => string '50' (length=2)
      'no_found_rows' => boolean false
      'order' => string 'DESC' (length=4)
  public 'tax_query' => 
    object(WP_Tax_Query)[2593]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
      public 'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
  public 'meta_query' => 
    object(WP_Meta_Query)[2594]
      public 'queries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'relation' => null
  public 'date_query' => boolean false
  public 'request' => string 'SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (

                    SELECT object_id

                    FROM wp_term_relationships

                    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1,4)

                ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC ' (length=322)
  public 'posts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'post_count' => int 0
  public 'current_post' => int -1
  public 'in_the_loop' => boolean false
  public 'comment_count' => int 0
  public 'current_comment' => int -1
  public 'found_posts' => int 0
  public 'max_num_pages' => int 0
  public 'max_num_comment_pages' => int 0
  public 'is_single' => boolean false
  public 'is_preview' => boolean false
  public 'is_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_archive' => boolean false
  public 'is_date' => boolean false
  public 'is_year' => boolean false
  public 'is_month' => boolean false
  public 'is_day' => boolean false
  public 'is_time' => boolean false
  public 'is_author' => boolean false
  public 'is_category' => boolean false
  public 'is_tag' => boolean false
  public 'is_tax' => boolean false
  public 'is_search' => boolean false
  public 'is_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_comment_feed' => boolean false
  public 'is_trackback' => boolean false
  public 'is_home' => boolean true
  public 'is_404' => boolean false
  public 'is_comments_popup' => boolean false
  public 'is_paged' => boolean false
  public 'is_admin' => boolean false
  public 'is_attachment' => boolean false
  public 'is_singular' => boolean false
  public 'is_robots' => boolean false
  public 'is_posts_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_post_type_archive' => boolean false
  public 'query_vars_hash' => string '2d0de38f6a4ebb9acf2b3533d94fd229' (length=32)
  public 'query_vars_changed' => boolean true
  public 'thumbnails_cached' => boolean false
  private 'stopwords' => null

boolean true
```

OR with `print_r`:

```
WP_Query Object ( [query] => Array ( [posts_per_page] => -1 [post_type] => post ) [query_vars] => Array ( [posts_per_page] => -1 [post_type] => post [error] => [m] => [p] => 0 [post_parent] => [subpost] => [subpost_id] => [attachment] => [attachment_id] => 0 [name] => [static] => [pagename] => [page_id] => 0 [second] => [minute] => [hour] => [day] => 0 [monthnum] => 0 [year] => 0 [w] => 0 [category_name] => [tag] => [cat] => [tag_id] => [author] => [author_name] => [feed] => [tb] => [paged] => 0 [comments_popup] => [meta_key] => [meta_value] => [preview] => [s] => [sentence] => [fields] => [menu_order] => [category__in] => Array ( ) [category__not_in] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1 ) [category__and] => Array ( ) [post__in] => Array ( ) [post__not_in] => Array ( ) [tag__in] => Array ( ) [tag__not_in] => Array ( ) [tag__and] => Array ( ) [tag_slug__in] => Array ( ) [tag_slug__and] => Array ( ) [post_parent__in] => Array ( ) [post_parent__not_in] => Array ( ) [author__in] => Array ( ) [author__not_in] => Array ( ) [ignore_sticky_posts] => [suppress_filters] => [cache_results] => 1 [update_post_term_cache] => 1 [update_post_meta_cache] => 1 [nopaging] => 1 [comments_per_page] => 50 [no_found_rows] => [order] => DESC ) [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object ( [queries] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] => category [terms] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1 ) [include_children] => [field] => term_id [operator] => NOT IN ) ) [relation] => AND ) [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object ( [queries] => Array ( ) [relation] => ) [date_query] => [request] => SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1,4) ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC [posts] => Array ( ) [post_count] => 0 [current_post] => -1 [in_the_loop] => [comment_count] => 0 [current_comment] => -1 [found_posts] => 0 [max_num_pages] => 0 [max_num_comment_pages] => 0 [is_single] => [is_preview] => [is_page] => [is_archive] => [is_date] => [is_year] => [is_month] => [is_day] => [is_time] => [is_author] => [is_category] => [is_tag] => [is_tax] => [is_search] => [is_feed] => [is_comment_feed] => [is_trackback] => [is_home] => 1 [is_404] => [is_comments_popup] => [is_paged] => [is_admin] => [is_attachment] => [is_singular] => [is_robots] => [is_posts_page] => [is_post_type_archive] => [query_vars_hash] => 2d0de38f6a4ebb9acf2b3533d94fd229 [query_vars_changed] => 1 [thumbnails_cached] => [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => )
```

***When I use this code (custom post type) it works (in the same template)...***

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'personnel', 
               'posts_per_page' => -1 
              );
 $all_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($all_posts_query->have_posts()) : $all_posts_query->the_post(); 
echo '*' . get_the_title() . '*';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo 'DEAD END';
exit;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your query, but there is some code (a plugin?) that remove from results the posts in the category having term id 1 or 4. (Normally category with term id 1 is 'uncategorized')

You can notice that looking at request performed

```
AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
  SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1,4)
)
```

and at `'category__not_in'` query var:

```
'category__not_in' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 1
```

Now its seems that `category__not_in` argument is added using `pre_get_posts` action.

If my guess is correct, you can try to remove all actions from that hook to prevent any query modification:

```
global $wp_filter;
$pgp_hooks = FALSE;
if ( isset( $wp_filter['pre_get_posts'] ) ) {
  // save hooks
  $pgp_hooks = $wp_filter['pre_get_posts']);
  // remove hooks
  unset( $wp_filter['pre_get_posts'] );
}
// set 'suppress_filters' param to true to skip sql filters
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post', 'suppress_filters' => true
);
// query
$all_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
// reset hooks after query is performed
if ( $pgp_hooks !== FALSE ) {
  $wp_filter['pre_get_posts'] = $pgp_hooks; 
}
// loop goes here...
```

Comment: Your qualified was very correct!!! Once again a plugin I think is very useful (Post Types Order) messed things up for me. I get the thing with unsetting pre_get_posts-filter. But I'm not sure what suppress_filter actually does? What "kind" of filters?

Comment: Anyway - It was your code with removing and restoring the pre_get_posts - filter hook that really made my day. THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld you're welcome. 'suppress_filter' remove all `'posts_*'` filters, like `'posts_where'`, `'posts_join'` and so on (there are 19 different `'posts_*'` filters iirc)